# how to display data from database on full calendar?

Tags: php, html, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

i have the following data

[image]

then i want to display in full calendar

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
    },
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url("absentMonthYearController/absentYearController/calendarShow/" . $nik) ?>',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
          var events = [];
          if (data != null) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              events.push({
                start: item.date,
                title: 'Present',
                display: 'background'
              })
            })
          }
          console.log('events', events);
        }
      })
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

the data doesn't appear in the calendar, but it does appear in console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {` is wrong for fullCalendar 5. That looks like the syntax from an earlier version. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/events-function shows the function's signature in v5, which is

   `function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) {`
2. You forgot to use the provided callback to return the events to fullCalendar. So your function is downloading the events and logging them, but they never make it to the calendar.

Therefore this:

```
events: function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url("absentMonthYearController/absentYearController/calendarShow/" . $nik) ?>',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      var events = [];
      if (data != null) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          events.push({
            start: item.date,
            title: 'Present',
            display: 'background'
          })
        })
      }
      console.log('events', events);
      successCallback(events);
    }
  })
}
```

should fix it.

---

P.S. Really you should also be using the start and end dates provided inside the fetchInfo object to send to your server, and the server should be using them to restrict the events it returns to only those which occur (or overlap) within those dates. That way you don't return a large number of events which mostly never get viewed, instead you only return what's relevant to the date range bein displayed.

Comment: Thank you for providing advice, but there are still errors. because the callback is not a function @ADyson

Comment: @Lr.Garox Sorry I noticed another issue as well as that. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: No problem. Please always check the documentation for the version you are using :-)